# I'm trying to write a program about modulus

Tags: java

I need help. I'm trying to write a program which depending on the value you're writing shows true or false depends on that if the value devision of a 7 without reminder.
I wrote this , but it doesn't work properly:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex05 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);   
    System.out.println("Please enter a value:");
        int  x = sc.nextInt();

        int a = x / 7;

        if (x % a == 0) 
        {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just do `if(x%7==0)` No need of using `a`.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you :)

Comment: Even simpler, `System.out.println(x%7==0);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you get it, without explanation. Simple math.

```
public class ex05 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);   
System.out.println("Please enter a value:");
    int  x = sc.nextInt();


    if (x % 7 == 0) 
    {
        System.out.println("true");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}
}
```

(
`a % b`

% is the modulus operator and it checks the remaining value after dividing `a` with `b`
)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of using `a`. The `%` operator gives the remainder. There is no use in using `/`. Do

```
int  x = sc.nextInt();

if (x % 7 == 0){
    System.out.println("true");
}else{
    System.out.println("false");
}
```

or just

```
System.out.println(x % 7 == 0);
```